# Get Rust struct for parent or subclass from an attribute of a PyAny object

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I have the following class structure defined in a Rust PyO3 Extension:

```rust
#[pyclass(subclass)]
struct Parent {
    foo: i32
}

#[pyclass(extends=Parent)]
struct Child {
    bar: i32
}
```

Then in Python, a pure python class contains an attribute which can be an instance of either the parent or the subclass, like so:

```py
class MyOtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # This attribute can be an instance of Parent or Child
        self.rust_class = Parent(foo=5)
```

Then in another PyO3 function, I want to be able to get the Rust struct for the `MyOtherClass.rust_class` attribute. I can easily get just one, say the Parent by doing the below function, but how would I be able to retrieve either the Parent of Child struct based on whatever the attribute is an instance of?

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn my_function(
    my_other_class: &PyAny //This is an instance of MyOtherClass
) -> i32 {
    let my_struct: Parent = my_other_class.getattr("rust_class").unwrap().extract().unwrap();
    my_struct.foo
}
```